# Cost of forking Augur

Tags: security, forks, augur

Augur Version 2 is scheduled for launch on July 28th 2020. How can the cost of forking Augur version 2 (by disputing a market resolution) be calculated in REP? How dies this cost compare to the cost of forking Augur version 1 (by disputing a market resolution)?